# How to write mixed text (normal and subscript) in docx using apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I will try to explain what I need.
I have a text that contains both normal-sized and subscript text (e.g. oxygene O2) which I would like to write to docx file using apache poi 3.9 library. I get either all text normal sized or subscript.  Is there a way to do that?
Here is my code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ApachePOI {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();

    run.setText("Oxygene - O");
    run.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUBSCRIPT);
    run.setText("2");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.docx");
        document.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, try this code -

```
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.ParagraphAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.VerticalAlign;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ApachePOI {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(); 
    XWPFParagraph paragraphOne = document.createParagraph();

    paragraphOne.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);

    XWPFRun paragraphOneRunOne = paragraphOne.createRun();
    paragraphOneRunOne.setFontSize(25);
    paragraphOneRunOne.setBold(true);
    paragraphOneRunOne.setText("Oxygene - O");

    XWPFRun paragraphOneRunTwo = paragraphOne.createRun();
    paragraphOneRunTwo.setFontSize(17);
    paragraphOneRunTwo.setBold(true);
    paragraphOneRunTwo.setSubscript(VerticalAlign.SUBSCRIPT);
    paragraphOneRunTwo.setText("2");

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C://test.docx");
        document.write(fos);
        fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: That works fine. But what if I want to write something like Na2CO3 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_carbonate)? Do I have to create new run for every subscript?

Comment: All the text in a given run must share the same formatting, that's just how the file format works

Comment: Yours is fine, I was just clarifying that for Na2Co3 you'll need 4 runs as there are 2 bits normal + 2 bits subscript